# Comparing multiple entity properties against list of entities

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this snippet of code:

```
var iList = new List<Entities.Ingredient>
{
    new Entities.Ingredient { Name = "tomato", Amount = 2.0 },
    new Entities.Ingredient { Name = "cheese", Amount = 100.0 }
};


var matches = new DataContext().Ingredients.Where(i => Comparer(i, iList));


private Boolean Comparer(Entities.Ingredient i, List<Entities.Ingredient> iList)
{
    foreach (var c in iList)
    {
        if (c.Name == iList.Name && c.Amount >= iList.Amount) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Preferably **without** being too verbose; *from x in y select z*... If thats at all possible.

Comment: You have an error in your Comparer function: the `i` variable is used inside the loop ans as parameter of the function.

Comment: Thanks. But this is pseudo-code. The real implementation compiles :)

Answer (score 2):

You could implement the IComparable interface on your class (Ingredient). That way you will at least keep the comparison code embedded in the class itself with no need for the extra method.
Here is a link:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasadh/IComparablePSD12062005010125AM/IComparablePSD.aspx

Comment: But then I'd have to re-implement that interface each time I would change my dbml-file (drag 'n drop LINQ to SQL).

Comment: ... Or just implement the interface in a partial class. Great! :)

Comment: Yes, that works. The alternative would be to use an external IEqualityComparer<T>, but the "partial class with interface" solution is more elegant.

Comment: In case you are interested in the IEqualityComparer<T>:  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx